# Circular Progress Bar in Alert Dialog Not Showing

Tags: android, dialog

I am using a custom layout for my alert dialog. The layout contains a ProgressBar and a TextView. I want a circular progress bar that keeps rotating. The TextView is visible but the ProgressBar is not visible.

**processing_dialog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.04"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        ></ProgressBar>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.13"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/progressBar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/processing_message"></TextView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**ProcessingDialog.java**

```
public class ProcessingDialog extends DialogFragment {

    private String messageToShow;
    private Dialog dialog;
    private Context context;
    private Activity activity;

    ProcessingDialog(String message, Activity activity){
        messageToShow = message;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstance){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);

        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.processing_dialog,null);
        ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.processing_message)).setText(messageToShow);
        builder.setView(v);
        dialog = builder.create();
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

**ViewDataActivity.java**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_data_activity);
        initView();
        dialog = new ProcessingDialog("Processing...", ViewDataActivity.this).onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.show();
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        ref.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first, do you have animations enabled in your device emulator? If not, check the options in Developer Mode.

Second, following the android docs [Dialogs | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#java), I suggest these changes:

#### `ProcessingDialog.java`

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstance){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    ...
    builder.setView(v);
    return builder.create();
}
```

#### `ViewDataActivity.java`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    dialog = new ProcessingDialog("Processing...", ViewDataActivity.this);
    dialog.setArguments(savedInstanceState);
    dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "MY_TAG");
    ...
}
```

Also, no need to pass activity as argument;`getActivity()` should handle that.

Comment: getActivity() was throwing NullPointerException. That is why I passed the Activity